# Relations on given set

Tags: real-analysis

Let V={1,...,5}.
I want to specify the smallest possible relation on V that is

- reflexive and symmetrical, but not transitive
- symmetrical and transitive, but not reflexive

is it possible to just take for example {(1,1)} for both ?

Comment: Obviously not. The relation can't be both reflexive and not reflexive, as well as transitive and not transitive. You will definitely need a different answer for each question.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetrical and transitive but not reflexive.

Smallest is the empty set.